# How to test the manager methods that consume the queryBuilder on symfony2 using PhpUnit

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, query-builder, symfony-2.7

This is the function I want to test on a manager (Genealogy Manager.php) When I run the phpunit command it gives the following error:

> Call to a member function getSingleScalarResult() on null in /home/majri/Documents/projects/IadDirectoryApp/vendor/iad-holding/genealogy-bundle/Iad/Bundle/GenealogyBundle/Manager/GenealogyManager.php on line 77

```
  /**
 * @param Genealogy $genealogy
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getCountManagerialLevelsByGenealogy(Genealogy $genealogy)
{
    $qb = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('gen');
    $qb->select('count(distinct(gen.level))') 
        ->where($qb->expr()->lt('gen.right', $genealogy->getRight()))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->gt('gen.left', $genealogy->getLeft()))
    ; 
    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

** My function of Unit test **

```
 public function testGetCountManagerialLevelsByGenealogy()
{
    $em =  $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManager::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $repository = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $em->expects($this->once())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->with('IadGenealogyBundle:Genealogy')
        ->will($this->returnValue($repository));

    $queryBuilder = $this->getMockBuilder(QueryBuilder::class)
        ->setMethods(['select','where','setParameter','getQuery'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $repository->expects($this->once())
        ->method('createQueryBuilder')
        ->with('gen')
        ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

    $queryBuilder->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('select')
        ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

    $queryBuilder->expects($this->at(1))
        ->method('where')
        ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

    $queryBuilder->expects($this->at(2))
        ->method('setParameter')
        ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

    $getQuery =  $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery')
        ->setMethods(array('setParameter', 'getSingleScalarResult'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();


    $getQuery->expects($this->once())
        ->method('setParameter')
        ->will($this->returnValue($queryBuilder));

    $getQuery->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getSingleScalarResult')
        ->will($this->returnValue(3));

    $queryBuilder->expects($this->at(3))
        ->method('getQuery')
        ->will($this->returnValue($getQuery));


    $genealogyManager = new GenealogyManager($em);

    $this->assertEquals(3, $genealogyManager->getCountManagerialLevelsByGenealogy($this->buildMockGenealogy(9)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this the only error but your query needs to be setting the parameters correctly like so:

```
$qb->select('count(distinct(gen.level))') 
    ->where($qb->expr()->lt('gen.right', ':getRight'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->gt('gen.left', ':getLeft'))
    ->setParameters(array(
        'genRight' => $genealogy->getRight(),
        'genLeft' => $genealogy->getLeft()
    ))
;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I have no problem at the level of the request but at the level of the unit test

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you forgot to mock the  `andWhere` method (which thus returns `null`)